# Javascript finding and grabbing paginated urls

Tags: javascript, pagination, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to get some data on a few sites. They tend to have paginated content and have a link but a lot of these sites do not follow the proper standard of adding 
`red=...`
attribute.

For example

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="next">Next Page</a>
```

and

```
<a class="non-uniform" href="?p=2" data-metrics-link="next"><span jawsonly="next page"></span></a>
```

how could I use javascript/ phantomjs to grab these paginated links?

**edit**

After looking around a bit I found some pieces of code that gave me some ideas. In the end I threw this together

```
var links = page.evaluate(function() {
    return [].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(link) {
        return link.getAttribute('href');
    });
});

var pages = links.join('\n').match(/\?page\=[0-9]/g);
pages = pages.sort().reduce(function(a, b){ if (b != a[0]) a.unshift(b); return a }, []);
pages.sort();
for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    console.log(i+" index "+pages[i]+" "+page.url+pages[i]);
}
```

What I noticed was that all paginated content had a `?page=` in the url somewhere so I looked how to grab that from phantomjs.

I am not sure how brittle this solution is, if there are anyone with some url's with paginated content who wouldn't mind sharing. I'd like to see if this works or if anyone could offer advise as how to improve this that would be great as well.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: I added some code that grabs all links, check them to see if they include `?page=` and sort those. It seems to work but might be brittle. If you know of any websites with paginated content you could post them for me to try this javascript on or you could assist in making this code more performant, less brittle, etc...